# how to connect php application with remote mysql database via ssh

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I am developing a php application that needs to connect to mysql database in a remote host.

I am using putty for SSH. Mysql workbench can successfully connect to the remote server and browse the database and the putty also connects without a problem and allow me to work with command line.

But the web application cannot connect.

It says access denied for user, the same username and password that I use to connect in putty command line .

---

I am using windows 7 and wamp sever 2.4 with Apache Version : 2.4.4

PHP Version :    5.4.16 .

---

can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uncomment skip-networking in mysql.ini in wamp server. it is working now

Answer (score 0):

This has **nothing** to do with SSH username and password, You must use these parameters :

```
$host = 'the host or IP that you are connecting with putty';
$username = 'mySQL username';
$password = 'mySQL passwrod';
//mySQL connection with above parameters .
```